# AngularJS directive get value from scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm passing my scope object to my directive and this works fine! After a get request I update my scope with a property called project. This contains some values like title, content, etc... If I log this everything is working fine but when I try to log scope.project I get the message undefined, but when I log scope I see the project object in the JSON tree... What can happens here?

All console logs show the correct information but I can't access it...

directive:

```
.directive('project', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope); // gives perfect json object including the project object
            console.log(scope.project.content); // gives undefined
        }
    }
}]);
```

template:

```
<div showcontent id="createdcontent"></div>
```

controller: (This is where I set the scope)

```
$http.get ('/api/projects/' + id)
    .success (function (data) {
        $scope.project = data.project;
    })
    .error (function (data){
        console.log("error: " + data);
    });
```

Many thanks

Comment: You must be setting the data asyncronously.

Comment: Oke fair enough, how can I do that?

Comment: How are you getting the `data` - post that call!

Comment: Why do you have $http injected in the directive? You are not showing us the full context. Basically you would need to wait till the data is retrieved.

Comment: I just do a GET request to the NodeJS server, but the weird thing is that if I inspect the browser I can see the data object in the console log of the scope but when I take one of my own variables it can't find data. It can find the data of the scope though

Comment: @blackbird It is a timing issue. Try this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112239/angularjs-directive-to-get-data-from-ajax-call-in-controller

Comment: Thanks @PSL that was the solution for my problem! You're the best!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something asynchronously, and the console.log wont wait for whatever asynchronous task http.get is doing, or when it returns, thus, the console log is being executed before the value of project is changed so it gives undefined. Add a callback to the  $http method you are using and then do that console.log, or send a callback with everything you want done when the request is finished. I had this issue a week ago and the problem was that my console.log was getting executed before the variable had been set by the asynchronous method. For example, using your http.get request on the controller, just add the console.log.

```
$http.get ('/api/projects/' + id)
    .success (function (data) {
        $scope.project = data.project;
        console.log(scope.project.content);
    })
    .error (function (data){
        console.log("error: " + data);
    });
```

Comment: Add the console.log() inside the success callback. Otherwise, your question is more related to methods of knowing when a callback returns so you don't deal with synchronization problems like this.

Comment: Also, your Controller shouldn't be doing http related task. Leave that to factories and services. Controllers drive the view, services worry about dealing with business logic(data access) and working with the scope as a best practice.