# simple directive to show static text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Our app is not using angular 1.3 (yet, we have to check the dependencies before updating), but I need to use [One-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) from 1.3 in some simple text attributes.

Wrote this directive to accomplish that

```
 return {
      scope: {
        'text': '='
      },
      restrict: 'AE',
      template: '{{ text }}',
      link: function link($scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    };
```

And it is used like this

```
<span static-text text="friend.name">
```

The problem is that it still adds a watch on `{{ text }}` (screenshot from Batarang)

[image]

Is there a simple way of displaying a text without the permanent watch? (looked at [this solution](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce/) but seems to be too much just for showing some text).

EDIT: I ended up using the solutions proposed by @arturgrzesiak and @PSL, @arturgrzesiak's solution was used when no async proccesing was present, and for the other scenarios I used @PSL's. Both solutions work, but I'll accept @PSL's since it covers more scenarios.

Comment: sure: remove `scope` and `template`, get text value from attrs and in the `link` function just set `element.innerHTML = text`.

Comment: Yeah you will have to do it manually. But it wont work if you are actually loading asynchronously in which case you would need to add a temp watch get the value set html and remove the watch.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak thanks for your comment, tried that but it didn't worked, first because `attrs.text` returns `friend.name` instead of the value of that expression, besides that, the innerHTML assignment looks like isn't working either since I get empty spans

Comment: @FelipePereira for that you need to use interpolation. `{{friend.name}}`. But it will create an additional watch for interpolation i guess.

Comment: @PSL I'm loading asynchronously the data (I've should clarify it on the question), so, this add/remove watch would be on the link? if you have implemented this; does this approach have a nice impact on performance?

Comment: @FelipePereira add/remove watch will obsviously remove watch once data is loaded(which is really what bindonce does as well). I provided an answer yesterday on similar lines.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535792/angularjs-directive-get-value-from-scope/27536154#27536154

Comment: @PSL using `{{friend.name}}` is going back to where I started :)

Comment: @FelipePereira Yeah.. That is the problem i mentioned in the previous comment. Does the directive only display the text? and it is supposed to be one time rendering right?

Comment: @FelipePereira Try this.. `return {
     
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope:{
       text:'='
      },
      link: function link($scope, element, attrs) {
        
         var unwatch = $scope.$watch('text', function(val){
            if(val){
              unwatch();
              element.html(val);
            } 
         })
      }
    };`

Comment: @PSL that worked, have to check some aspects about performance but it works, and it answers the question, so if you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it, thanks

Comment: @FelipePereira Sure il post it..

Comment: @arturgrzesiak if you give more time I'll run more tests so I can collect more data to make a choice, both answers worked, but I have to pick one, for your effort you deserve a good reason of why I choose one instead of the other

Comment: @PSL read previous comment

Comment: @FelipePereira if the other answer works for you, you should accept that (Remember in places you might be loading data asynchronously where it wont work).. I just added mine to support async data binding as well... I am removing mine as of now. If you think my answer is useful, please let me know i will undelete.

Comment: @PSL I think your answer is useful, just asked for a little more time to run more tests

Comment: @PSL admit it, you delete it just to get the hat :P

Comment: @FelipePereira haha lol.. Actually no, but i realized after deleting that i got a hat.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some advantages that you get by having a watch. One example is in your actual code you are setting the data asynchronously which means the bound variable gets updated during the next digest cycle. But it's overkill (So `bindonce` or other watch removal libraries or 1.3 two-way binding exist) in some case. Here is one thing you can do, just use a watch until you get the data and then remove it once you have got it and set the html manually from the directive.

```
return { 
   restrict: 'AE', 
   link: function link($scope, element, attrs) { 
       var unwatch = $scope.$watch(attrs.staticText, function(val){ //Set up temp watch
          if(val){ 
            unwatch(); //Unwatch it
            element.html(val); //Set the value
          } 
       });
    } 
};
```

and just use it as

```
<span static-text="friend.name">
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a bit more convoluted than what I proposed in the comment.

```
app.directive('once', function($parse){

  return function(scope, element, attrs){

      var parsed = $parse(attrs.once)(scope);
      element.html(parsed);

  }

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZiCxWoOkPjp7N2Eoab8n?p=preview)

Comment: fyi.. You do not need to inject `$parse`, you could as well use `scope.$eval(attrs.once)`